# How do I create a white background for my text area (change it from a different colour)?

Tags: css, textarea

My website - http://www.automated-stores.com has the strange feature of a blue-ish background for text areas, seen more specifically here: http://www.automated-stores.com/vending-machines-business-electronics-cosmetics-perfume

I didn't code the website, but I suppose that to change this it would have to be in the stylesheet.css, does anyone know what code to enter/change?

I thought it would be this:

```
input,textarea,select { 
    padding: 1px; 
    border: solid 1px #000000; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    color:#000000; 
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

(the colours were different before) but I have changed it several times with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through your source code and you need to find your style.css under your root and change this:

```css
input,textarea,select { 
    padding: 1px; 
    border: solid 1px #5c8593; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    color:#42484d; 
    background-color:#224f5f;
}
```

to this:

```css
background-color:#ffffff;
```

Remember this will affect everything with the class of input, textarea, select. I used the chrome inspect and firebug lite tool to verify this and it worked. If you only want to effect text areas bg color do this:

```css
input,select { 
    padding: 1px; 
    border: solid 1px #5c8593; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    color:#42484d; 
    background-color:#224f5f;
}

textarea { 
    padding: 1px; 
    border: solid 1px #5c8593; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    color:#42484d; 
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: if you change the color/border and all that to white. It will look like it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

The specific rules changing the color of the `textarea` on the page you gave (the second link) is in `style.css` line 44:

```css
input, textarea, select {
    background-color: #224F5F; // This is the blue background
    border: 1px solid #5C8593;
    color: #42484D;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

If it is just textareas that you want to style but dont want to touch the formatting you can do one of two things:

**Option 1**

Keep CSS as it is and add this underneath:

```css
textarea {
    background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

I dont like doing this as it makes the CSS to rigid and lots of !important declarations makes managing the style very difficult.

**Option 2**

Change line 44 styling to:

```css
input, textarea, select {
    border: 1px solid #5C8593;
    color: #42484D;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 1px;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

input, select {
    background-color: #224F5F;
}
```

Comment: I used option 2 to change the stylesheet, but the comment box still hasn't changed colour!

Comment: @NellyMatorina I'm looking at your site and I'm changing the background color freely for all text areas and inputs by editing background-color on line 44 of your CSS. This is 100% the problem, are you making sure that you have removed background-color from the line 44 declaration as I have above?

Comment: I changed the code to this:input, textarea, select {
    border: 1px solid #5C8593;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 1px;
}

textarea {
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #224f5f;
    color:#000;
}

input, select {
    background-color: #ffffff;

but it still isn't working, for example here:  
http://www.automated-stores.com/vending-machines-business-electronics-cosmetics-perfume

Comment: Hey Nelly, your CSS hasn't changed at all from when I first reviewed it. I think you may be uploading your changes to a different unused file?

Comment: I am updating it on my wp-admin editor on wordpress, do you know any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it's not updating. You're best bet is to open the style.css manually and changing it to what you want. WP is clearly messing you about a bit.

Answer (score 0):

your `<textarea>` have attribute `<... class="textarea"...` You could add this to your stylesheet

```css
.textarea {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question does it, provided that you insert it e.g. in a `style` element after the tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`. The external style sheet sets the background color etc. in a simple manner, which can easily be overridden, provided that you place your code *after* that `link` tag.

If this does not appear to work, check, in a browser, the HTML source code of the page. It is possible that the server software does some modifications to your code or that your browser has got an old version of the page (Ctrl+F5 should help then).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simply targeting the textareas and changing their background colour and giving them a border.

```css
textarea {
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #224f5f;
    color:#000;
}
```